# "The daemon is being inhibited" error message when mounting volumes on a partitioned external HD

Tags: mount, external-hdd

I'm having a great deal of difficulty with an external hard drive. I'm currently running a dual boot system (XP Service Pack 3 and Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwahl) on a Dell Inspiron B120.

I'm trying to set up a new 80 GB Hitachi external HD. Using GParted, I formatted the drive and set up the partitions. The partitioning scheme is as follows

- 10GB NTFS Primary,
- 2GB Linux-Swap Primary,
- 50GB FAT32 Primary,
- 12GB Unallocated.

After applying those changes, I went into Disk Utility and the HD appears along with the correct partitions. When I try to mount the volumes for partitions 1 and 3, I get a pop-up stating:

```
Error Mounting Volume
An error occurred while performing an operation on "Home"
(Partition 3 of HTS548080m9AT00): The daemon is being inhibited.
```

When I try to to check the filesystem I get a pop-up stating:

```
Error Checking filesystem on volume
An error occurred while performing an operation on "Home"
(Partition 3 of HTS548080m9AT00): The daemon is being inhibited.
```

Throughout the time that I'm attempting to troubleshoot the problem, the external drive light is on and blinking. With my frustration hitting a boiling point, I try to shut down the drive and remove it so that I can plug in a different external HD that works PERFECTLY.

However, when I try to shut down and safely remove the drive, I get a pop-up stating:

```
Error Detaching Drive
An error occurred while performing an operation on "80GB Hard Disk"
(HTS548080m9AT00): The daemon is being inhibited.
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm a newbie and not that skilled with terminal commands, so please dumb it down for me if you request specific command output.

Answer (score 10):

The error message "The daemon is being inhibited" is probably the clue here.

There is a ubuntuforum entry [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1604563) with a few suggestions that you can copy and paste into a terminal:

**Potential Solution 1**

```
sudo killall udisks
```

**Potential Solution 2**

```
sudo apt-get install udisks libgdu0 gnome-disk-utility policykit-desktop-privileges --reinstall
```

Comment: I've found that this also occurs when you try to mount or unmount disks (using `udisks`/Nautilus) while GParted is running.

Comment: Instead of killing all processes, it should be enough to use `ps aux` to look for `udisks --inhibit` and kill all those processes (as `root`).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use your rear usb (directly connected with motherboard) port. use Both usb cable form HD.
Use Disk Utility application to check that your HD partitions are ok or not. If it does not show any error then just format the each partition (not full sdx ). Now try to mount.

If you will fail please post the output of this command [keep connected your HD]

```
sudo -i
fdisk -l
```